# Design this layout for all devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem to understand how can design my images to fit all resolutions/densities/sizes of screens.

My question is this:

Provide independent density images allow images appear the same size in all resolutions densities. But if the physical size of the screen is larger, the image will be smaller relative to the user's point of view.

Is this right?

For example, I have taken as a base line a Nexus S 4" 480x800 hdpi. I've designed a logo to fit into center of screen. Then I 've scaled the logo to mdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi according to [android developers webpage](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

When I change the device into android designer to Nexus 6 the logo appears smaller. It is due to physical size of the screen?

I don't know if its  a silly question, sorry.

This is the layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splashLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/spashlogo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: You should create a spashlogo as following different size(drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi)inside the res folder,which will be automatically set as a physical device.For eg:(48*48, 72*72, 96*96, 144*144).there is no problem with the layout .

Comment: Use vector formats like VectorDrawable or SVG.

Comment: DP relates directly to mm on screen, so if you set something on dp its size will be the same in mm in every screen.